# Problem in upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04lts and today I'm upgrading it to 16.04 lts. During upgradation, my laptop got shut down and now when I'm restarting it command line is coming and I'm not able to switch to gui, I've tried startx but after this command I'm seeing only desktop folders and cross mouse cursor and then I've tried sudo service lightdm start but after running this command black screen is blinking with cursor, can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can use live Disk of Ubuntu and go to your OS, after that try to upgrade your OS again or fix missing files which probably deleted somehow!
I had this problem before, hope help you too

Comment: Thanks for reply, can you provide some link on how to do this?

Comment: use this [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/726071/repairing-broken-installation-from-live-usb-without-losing-data)